# I have a 3 phase power at home, the third line is always at 220V, why is this the case?

Tags: voltage, three-phase

I have a 3 phase 220V power at home and L1, L2, L3 is at 220V.

When I measure the voltage using my electric meter as follows:

- L1 & L2 = 220V
- L1 & L3 = 220V
- L2 & L3 = 220V

Yes my electric power at home is 220V, but I wanted to have a 110V socket at home so what I did was take L2 and take another line from the grounding rod which is earth from the ground, and the output changed to 110V, I did it.

What I'm really curious about is when I take L3 and earth ground it always outputs at 220V.

Why is this the case?

I did a test to make sure:

- L1 & earth ground = 110V
- L2 & earth ground = 110V
- L3 & earth ground = 220V

Can someone explain to me why L3 is always at 220V?

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: A 220V home system shouldn't have 110V anywhere.  Outlets in the US are 110V, and that comes from a split 220V.  If your outlets are 220V, then there shouldn't 110V anywhere in your house.

Comment: Is this a high-leg delta configuration?

Comment: Are you sure about L3 to earth at 220V  (is it maybe a bit lower)?

Comment: If L3 has 208V it should be high-leg delta, right?

Comment: A 220 V high leg delta system would have 190V to neutral.

Comment: @The Photo I live in the philippines

Comment: @jre don't many us homes have 110v outlets generally and some 220v outlets in kitchen and laundry?

Comment: @Passerby:  Yes, they do.  220V outlets are the exception to the rule of 110V in US houses, though.  Any place that has all 220V outlets won't have 110V available.  The US system splits 220V into 2 X 110V.  You have 110V from hot to neutral and 220V across to hots.

Comment: @VincentRet Please edit all additional information into the body of the question itself. Just posting it inside the discussion will make it difficult to find. You can add some "update"-caption to make clear that the information was added later during discussion.